# iText 7 table's bottom border not being drawn

Tags: c#, wpf, itext, itext7

I am using iText 7 for creating a table inside the PDF file. I have successfully created the table but the table's bottom border is not being drawn.

Screenshot of the Result:

[image: Screenshot of the Result]

My Code:

```
 private void Convert()
    {
        String dest = "D:/addingTable.pdf";
        var table = new Table(1, true);
        Border b = new SolidBorder(ColorConstants.RED, 5);
        table.SetBorder(b);
        using (var writer = new PdfWriter(dest))
        {
            using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer))
            {
                var doc = new Document(pdf);

                var name = new Paragraph("Hello World!").SetFontColor(ColorConstants.BLUE).SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER).SetFontSize(13);
                table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(name));
                doc.Add(table);
            }
        }
        Process.Start(dest);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly create the `Table` with `largeTable` support set to `true`:

```
var table = new Table(1, true);
```

This allows to add large tables to a PDF without the whole table structure having to reside in memory at the same time: You can add it piecewise and flush all aggregated data every once in a while.

```
[add first few rows]
doc.Add(table);
[add next few rows]
table.Flush();
[add next few rows]
table.Flush();
...
[add final rows]
table.Complete();
```

In your code you forgot the final

```
table.Complete();
```

(or you simply did not want to create the table with `largeTable` support to start with).